# Excel VBA to find Quadruplets from a given data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

The below VBA code extracts most common repeating pairs and triplets from a given data which requires 6 columns of data (A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1), and displays their number of occurrences. I would like to have this code to extract only quadruplets from a data set which contains 22 columns of data (A1,B1,C1,....U1,V1), and display the number of their occurrences in a similar way. I am not sure if this is too much data to handle for excel.

```
Sub MostCommonPairAndTriplet()
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim strPair As String
Dim strTriplet As String
Dim wsResult As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("A:F"))

If Not rng Is Nothing Then

'Get the result worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set wsResult = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
If wsResult Is Nothing Then
Set wsResult = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
wsResult.Name = "Results"
Else
wsResult.UsedRange.Delete
End If
'column labels
With wsResult
.Range("B1").Value = "Value1"
.Range("C1").Value = "Value2"
.Range("D1").Value = "Count"
.Range("F1").Value = "Value1"
.Range("G1").Value = "Value2"
.Range("H1").Value = "Value3"
.Range("I1").Value = "Count"
End With
On Error GoTo 0

'Find Pairs
lRow = 2
For Each c In rng
    If c.Column <= 5 Then
        For i = 1 To 6 - c.Column
            strPair = c.Value & "_" & c.Offset(0, i).Value

            On Error Resume Next
            lRow2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strPair, wsResult.Range("A:A"), False)
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                wsResult.Range("A" & lRow).Value = strPair
                wsResult.Range("B" & lRow).Value = c.Value
                wsResult.Range("C" & lRow).Value = c.Offset(0, i).Value
                wsResult.Range("D" & lRow).Value = 1
                lRow = lRow + 1
            Else
                wsResult.Range("D" & lRow2).Value = wsResult.Range("D" & lRow2).Value + 1
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End If
Next c

'Find Triplets
lRow = 2
For Each c In rng
    If c.Column <= 5 Then
        For i = 1 To 6 - c.Column
            For j = 1 To 6 - c.Offset(0, i).Column
                strTriplet = c.Value & "_" & c.Offset(0, i).Value & "_" & c.Offset(0, i + j).Value

                On Error Resume Next
                lRow2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strTriplet, wsResult.Range("E:E"), False)
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    wsResult.Range("E" & lRow).Value = strTriplet
                    wsResult.Range("F" & lRow).Value = c.Value
                    wsResult.Range("G" & lRow).Value = c.Offset(0, i).Value
                    wsResult.Range("H" & lRow).Value = c.Offset(0, i + j).Value
                    wsResult.Range("I" & lRow).Value = 1
                    lRow = lRow + 1
                Else
                    wsResult.Range("I" & lRow2).Value = wsResult.Range("I" & lRow2).Value + 1
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
Next c
End If

wsResult.Columns("E").Clear
wsResult.Columns("A").Delete

'Sort the pairs
With wsResult
.Columns("A:C").Sort Key1:=.Range("C2"), Order1:=xlDescending
.Columns("E:H").Sort Key1:=.Range("H2"), Order1:=xlDescending
End With


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: You will have 7,315 quads for each row. So I would work with VBA arrays and collections to gather the data, rather than frequently referring to the worksheet.  Will the data in each row be sorted?  Will the data be Integers? What about duplicate Quads in the same row?

Comment: Data sorting would be nice to have but it is not essential.  the data are integers, and in each row they are unique. No same value, so there won't be duplicate  Quads in a row.

Comment: If the data in each row is sorted, it makes it easier to compare quads **unless** you are saying that the order of the integers makes a difference (in other words, 1-2-3-4 is different from 4-2-3-1).  If the order makes a difference, then you will have 175,560 quads per row, and would probably require 64 bit Excel.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood your question at the beginning. In this case, 1-2-3-4 an 4-3-2-1 are the same. So they should be treated as same, and in your example, there are 2 occurrences of the same numbers together here.

Comment: So the original question stands -- will the entries in each row of your source data be already sorted, or does that have to be taken into account when creating the quads?

Comment: yes, the data is already sorted, the values are in increasing order. But Quads may be distributed in different cells in a row.

Comment: (a,b,d,e,f,g,k,l,m,q) (b,c,e,f,m,q,r,p,x,z) if you take these two rows with 10 values for simplicity as an example, (I used letters instead of numbers, because numbers can be one or two digits only, but no three digits), here (b,e,f,q) is a quad existing in both rows. So the occurrence of these 4 values in two rows is 2, irrespective of their ordering in the columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63743/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the large number of possible Quads when dealing with 22 cells per row, I suggest a different approach than what you have used for doubles and triplets.

I would create a User Defined Object (class) to contain information as to both the contents of the quad, and a count.  (I also threw in a method to create an array of the Quad items).  Then I would collect the quads in a dictionary object -- in the code below I used early-binding (set a reference, under `Tools --> References` to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`, but if this is going to be distributed, you should probably change to late-binding.

When collecting the quads after the first line, we can use the dictionary to test if the quad already exists; if it does, we add one to the count; if it does not, we store it as a new quad.

The range is sized by looking for the last row in column A; and the last column in row 1.  It assumes your data starts in A1 (as you show on your worksheet), and that there are no header rows.  If that is not the case, you may need to make some adjustments.

It also assumes that the entries in each row are sorted.  If that is not the case, you will need to add a sort routine before generating the Quad.

**EDIT**:  *Note that the routine will crash (with a 1004 error) if your desired output includes more than 2^20 quads, due to Excel's row limit. There are at least two ways to handle this:*

- *Increase the threshold so as to only output quads that have a count of 2, 3 or whatever is necessary to fit in a single set of columns (probably the simplest method)*
- *change the output routine so as to spread the output over multiple sets of columns.*

### Class Module

> Be sure to rename this to cQuad

```
Option Explicit
'Rename cQuad
Private pQ1 As Long
Private pQ2 As Long
Private pQ3 As Long
Private pQ4 As Long
Private pCnt As Long
Private pArr As Variant

Public Property Get Q1() As Long
    Q1 = pQ1
End Property
Public Property Let Q1(Value As Long)
    pQ1 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Q2() As Long
    Q2 = pQ2
End Property
Public Property Let Q2(Value As Long)
    pQ2 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Q3() As Long
    Q3 = pQ3
End Property
Public Property Let Q3(Value As Long)
    pQ3 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Q4() As Long
    Q4 = pQ4
End Property
Public Property Let Q4(Value As Long)
    pQ4 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Arr() As Variant
    Dim V(1 To 4)
        V(1) = Me.Q1
        V(2) = Me.Q2
        V(3) = Me.Q3
        V(4) = Me.Q4
    Arr = V
End Property

Public Property Get Cnt() As Long
    Cnt = pCnt
End Property
Public Property Let Cnt(Value As Long)
    pCnt = Value
End Property
```

## Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub CheckForQuads()
    Dim cQ As cQuad, dQ As Dictionary
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim V, W
    Dim sKey As String

Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 10)

With wsData
    I = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row
    J = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Last Column
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(I, J))
End With

Set dQ = New Dictionary
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)

    'Size array for number of combos in each row
    V = Combos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vSrc, I, 0))

    'create an object for each Quad, including each member, and the count
    For J = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    Set cQ = New cQuad
        With cQ
            .Q1 = V(J, 1)
            .Q2 = V(J, 2)
            .Q3 = V(J, 3)
            .Q4 = V(J, 4)
            .Cnt = 1
            sKey = Join(.Arr, Chr(1))

            'Add one to the count if Quad already exists
            If Not dQ.Exists(sKey) Then
                dQ.Add sKey, cQ
            Else
                dQ(sKey).Cnt = dQ(sKey).Cnt + 1
            End If

        End With
    Next J
Next I

'Output the results
'set a threshold
Const TH As Long = 1

'Size the output array
I = 0
For Each V In dQ.Keys
    If dQ(V).Cnt >= TH Then I = I + 1
Next V
ReDim vRes(0 To I, 1 To 5)

'Headers
vRes(0, 1) = "Value 1"
vRes(0, 2) = "Value 2"
vRes(0, 3) = "Value 3"
vRes(0, 4) = "Value 4"
vRes(0, 5) = "Count"

'Output the data
I = 0
For Each V In dQ.Keys
    Set cQ = dQ(V)
    With cQ
        If .Cnt >= TH Then
            I = I + 1
            vRes(I, 1) = .Q1
            vRes(I, 2) = .Q2
            vRes(I, 3) = .Q3
            vRes(I, 4) = .Q4
            vRes(I, 5) = .Cnt
        End If
    End With
Next V

'Output the data
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Sort key1:=.Columns(.Columns.Count), _
        order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False
End With
End Sub

Function Combos(Vals)
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, L As Long, M As Long
    Dim V

ReDim V(1 To WorksheetFunction.Combin(UBound(Vals), 4), 1 To 4)
M = 0
For I = 1 To UBound(Vals) - 3
    For J = I + 1 To UBound(Vals) - 2
        For K = J + 1 To UBound(Vals) - 1
            For L = K + 1 To UBound(Vals)
                M = M + 1
                V(M, 1) = Vals(I)
                V(M, 2) = Vals(J)
                V(M, 3) = Vals(K)
                V(M, 4) = Vals(L)
            Next L
        Next K
    Next J
Next I

Combos = V

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to explain it further. @Ron Rosenfeld.

Comment: @Max You are welcome.  What are you seeing now with your large number of rows data source, in terms of rows of output and performance?

Comment: After increasing threshold value to 5, it got faster. I still haven't tried for all the rows I got. but it works smoothly until 200 rows.

Comment: I just finished testing 783 rows of data, and it gave 470145 results in about 24 minutes. The highest occurrence of a quad is 16.

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I guess we have some idea now of how much data can be handled by Excel.  I would guess that if there is much more data, you might require the 64-bit version.  BTW, what is this being used for?

Comment: Yes, definitely. This will be used for a prediction analysis in a game by a friend of mine.

Comment: I have a question. Would it be possible to save and list the IDs of each group of values they are in (IDs for each 22 number sets) with this script? Can Excel handle this? E.g. if A,B,C,D quad is counted as 4, and this quad appears in ID:1, ID:20, ID:80, and ID200 etc.

Comment: What is `ID`? What is an `A,B,C,D quad`?  Why is there a question as to whether *Excel can handle this*?  Why can't you just add it as a property of  `cQaud`?

Comment: My apologies. What I meant with  ID unique identification number for each row. Since there will be several pairs in different rows and hence IDs, it'd be a challenge I thought. My question may be was not proper, I am sorry about that. I meant if Excel is right tool for this task

Comment: Just add a collection (or dictionary) of the row numbers as a property of `cQuad`.  If Classes are new to you, start with Chip Pearsons excellent [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx)

Comment: So far as asking about which tool is the best one to use, that is not something I can advise you. It is a task which can be accomplished in many ways, and opinions vary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Ron. I will go through what you've suggested. I may ask your advice along the way.

Comment: @Max You will learn a lot working with classes; and also see how much easier it can be to follow the logic of what you are trying to do.